# grails 3.3.8. How to work around the bug java.sql.Date property is type-mismatched

Tags: date, grails3

There is a serious bug in grails which means that any form using scaffolding/fields plugin/command objects with data binding fail.

See: https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues/11126

My app has many domain objects with Dates (without time or time zone, such as birthDate, issueDate, validUntilDate, memerableDate etc.etc.)

Sadly, the issue is closed without any fix for grails 3.3.8. Grails 4 is far down the road in terms of being stable enough to switch to it  (at least 6 months).

I have spent some 2 man weeks (a serious amount of my money) trying to find some sort of workaround. The issue is now critical.

Currently, I have got to the point where I can both display and create domain objects with java.time.LocalDate (I switched to this in preference to java.sql.Date as its not possible to override the behaviour of java.sql.Date using fields plugin as views/_fields/Date/_widget.gsp etc refers to java.util.date)

But I cannot edit them.

The hack I use to create them is this:

User.groovy:

```
   class User {
       String name 
       java.time.LocalTime birthDate
       // etc
   }
```

UserController.groovy

```
def save(User user) {
    user.clearErrors() // this fixed the spurious "property is type-mismatched"
   java.time.LocalDate birthDate = LocalDate.of(params.int('birthDate_year'), params.int("birthDate_month"), params.int("birthDate_day"))
   user.birthDate = birthDate
   userService.save(user)
   :
}
```

This works.

The problem is when I want to edit the object, using the standard scaffolded/geneated gsp like this:

```
<g:form resource="${this.user}" method="PUT">
    <g:hiddenField name="version" value="${this.user?.version}" />
    <fieldset class="form">
        <f:all bean="user"/>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset class="buttons">
        <input class="save" type="submit" value="${message(code: 'default.button.update.label', default: 'Update')}" />
    </fieldset>
</g:form>
```

It gives:

```
Cannot cast object '2119-01-02' with class 'java.time.LocalDate' to class 'java.util.Date'
```

I tried to override the views/_fields/LocalDate/_widget.gsp with manual conversion from the LocalDate to date thusly:

```
<g:datePicker name="${property}"  precision="day" value="${java.sql.Date.valueOf(value)}" default="none" noSelection="['':'']"/>
```

But this gives:

```
cannot resolve which method to invoke for [null] due to overlapping prototypes between: [class java.lang.String] [class java.time.LocalDate]
```

Which I cant find a way to get working (have tried about 30 variations on the above)

Cany anyone think of any way to get around this problem so we can allow the user to edit objects with dates (without times and timezones) via fields plugin in grails?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same bug, but using Grails 2.5.5.
When I add a Date field in an existing class, the IDE add the import:
import java.sql.Date

In this condition I had the type mismatch error, but deleting the import, everything works ok.